# Pinch on windows phone 7 emulator using machine without multitouch support. Can it be done?

Tags: windows-phone-7, emulation

I'm playing around with wp7 using the emulator. I'd like to play with multitouch on the emulator, but my machine doesn't have multi touch support (it's just a standard mouse/keyboard setup).

Is their any way to do this?

I know that double clicking zooms/unzooms, but I'm looking for pinch-specific interaction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I've gathered, I don't think this can be done without multitouch hardware support on the development machine.  I hope this will change when the final version is released (but it seems kind of late in the game for such a change)

If this is wrong, please let me know.

Comment: note:  I wouldn't rule out http://multitouchvista.codeplex.com/, and it might work for some.  For whatever reason, I couldn't get it to work on my machine and I don't really want to spend a day figuring out what went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Windows7 and have two mice you could try http://multitouchvista.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

http://jonas.follesoe.no/SimulatingMultitouchOnTheWindowsPhone7Emulator.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Try using wheel scrolling and left mouse key down + scrolling up / down.

Answer (score 1):

Try mouse with Alt, Control or Shift pressed. That's how you do pinch on the iPhone emulator.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but this doesn't appear to work for me. The click/drag with those keys pressed function the same way that it would if the key's weren't pressed.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [in the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999263/affordable-options-for-multi-touch-desktop-device-to-test-apps-on-windows-phone/4002357#4002357), you could always [emulate multitouch](http://jonas.follesoe.no/SimulatingMultitouchOnTheWindowsPhone7Emulator.aspx) until you have an actual phone to test on.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 supports multitouch screens so if you got one you CAN use it with the emulator for real multitouches, according to MS people I talked to. Might be cheaper still to just get a real WP7 device? :-D