# Affordable options for multi touch desktop device (To test apps on Windows phone 7 emulator)?

Tags: windows-7, windows-phone-7, user-input, multi-touch

I am looking to get into Windows phone 7 development. I am running Windows 7 and i know it supports multi touch which i can then use in the emulator if enabled.

Is there any way for me to try this out without me paying a premium for a tablet, phone or touch monitor?

Many thanks,
Kohan.

Comment: I am using the dual mouse option. Seems to work quite well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always [emulate multitouch](http://jonas.follesoe.no/SimulatingMultitouchOnTheWindowsPhone7Emulator.aspx) until you have an actual phone to test on.

Answer (score 1):

Just found this, how to make your own surface like touch screen. Wow!

http://geekswithblogs.net/kobush/archive/2009/03/10/129993.aspx